# When an old question is poor quality, but end result is a useful answer, how to review close vote?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

Here is an example question, that I saw when reviewing close requests:

[Check if URL exists in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908017/check-if-url-exists-in-ruby)

If this question were asked today on Stack Overflow, it would be closed because it shows no attempt at a solution in the question. It is pretty much "Give me teh codez pls?"

However, it seems to me there is value in the question and answers, for future visitors wanting an answer. Generally, once a question is answered well, the quality I would care about in the question is: Does it turn up for relevant search terms?

I quite often find myself split between site policy on no-effort questions, versus the good answers, and utility of them being available in future.

Is there a normal way to resolve this? Should I mark the question as "Leave Open" or vote to Close it for violating site policy? It seems due to algorithms in the review code that I get presented with making this decision on a daily basis. Mostly, I click on "Skip" . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing off-topic questions is important in preventing further questions of the sort, by transmitting the message that that kind of post is off-topic. If a casual user sees lots of low-effort questions closed because of that, they will (hopefully) be less likely to post low-effort questions of their own. If you see a still-open "give me teh code plz" question, vote-to-close it to help prevent others like it.

If the thread as a whole is useful, or it has useful answers, make sure you upvote the useful answers so the question is not automatically deleted. If you feel the question can be modified to make it more useful as a resource for future visitors, and more visible in search engines, then do so as well. (If you're voting to close, though, make sure that the low-effort-ness that got it closed still shines through. On the other hand, if you *can* edit that out, then it's unlikely the question requires closing.)

Comment: I could easily have accepted any of the three answers so far, they are all good and share the same general advice. I have picked this one because I feel the second paragraph is something I can bear in mind to help me act consistently whilst reviewing the type of question I was struggling with.

Answer (score 6):

With positive votes and upvoted answers, a closed question will not be automatically deleted. Moreover, closed questions can still be found when searching for it, either via Google or with the Stack Overflow search engine.

If you feel the question should be closed, vote to close it. The answers won't be lost.

Answer (score 3):

The main aim of closing a question is to prevent (new) answers. It won't delete already posted answers. Old answers will be deleted only if it is very low quality post. So while reviewing questions for *close votes* look at the question.

There are [lots of old and closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed:1%20created:2008..2010) which are not deleted. So closing a question won't cause to delete it. Closed questions are deleted if it is *really* not suitable for the site.

So you should close the question if it off-topic without worrying about it's helpful answers.